# Unwanted onItemSelected calls after restoring application state

Tags: android, spinner, listener, state, restore

Hi,
I've got some Spinner objects that, when selected, change the contents of an `EditText` and a Button. All is working fine until I toggle the screen on and off.
 I made the application orientation landscape-only and thus on toggling the screen on and off causes the activity to be destroyed.

The problem that occurs here is that I lose all the state information of the Spinner, EditText and Button objects.
So I tried to solve this problem with the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods, by setting back the state of the Spinner, Button and EditText in that order.
The problem is that, for some reason, the `onItemSelected` method is called after I restored the state of the Button and EditText, and thus they are set to their default values.
I tried disabling the onItemSelected listeners temporarily, but as soon as I enabled them again, the onItemSelected method is called and resets the Button and EditText state.

Note: I only want to restore the state after the app has been killed by the system, not by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global boolean variable and on restore set it to true. In onItemSelected you can check this variable and if it true you will not change button and editText content, just set this variable to false.
In onRestoreInstaceState:

```
wasRestored = true;
```

In onItemSelected:

```
if(wasRestored){
   wasRestored=false;
   return;
} else {//change editText and Button content}
```

Comment: I tried this by setting it to true at the start of the onRestoreInstanceState method and setting it back to false at the end. This doesn't work though, however when I don't set it back to false it does work, but then my Spinner obviously doesn't work anymore. So from my perspective, it seems that the onItemSelected method is called after the onRestoreInstanceState method, I've got no clue where/why though.

Comment: you should try to set it to false at the onItemSelected, not at the onRestoreInstanceState. if(variable){variable=false;return;} - something like this.

Comment: Okay, I corrected it but am still having the issue. So I tried to find out what happens with some logging. The following methods I've implemented are called when turning the screen back on, without your suggestion: onCreate - init (Spinner, Button and EditText are initialized) - onRestoreInstanceState - onItemSelected - onItemSelected. By adding the global boolean the first onItemSelected call disappears but still somehow somewhere onItemSelected is called.

Comment: Well, Did you try in on restore set spinner into position, than was before, then maybe your data in edittext and button will be reloaded, but it'll be the same?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean, I actually managed to fix it by adding a second global boolean to work around the second call to onItemSelected. This isn't ideal ofcourse, but it works for now. I'm still trying to figure out why onItemSelected is called (twice) after onRestoreInstanceState.